# Twitter Trends by categories

Tags: api, rest, twitter

Just curious to know that whether there is a way in twitter to check for the popular trends in categories e.g.  'automobile', 'sports', 'forex' etc, just like we have the search.twitter.com providing us with the search for keywords. is there a way we can search for particular trends associated with some category.

Thanks,

Vaibhav

Answer (score 1):

Well as far as I have seen, there is no api to extract trends based on topics BUT you can monitor tweets containing particular key words through the public streaming API. Check the twitter api documentation for more.. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis

Comment: Ya true! that we can even get through the search.twitter.com REST api, i am more interested in categorized trends here, thanks for the input though!